# Placement of Dashboard and sub category tabs in UI

Tags: html, css, user-interface, user-experience

I am in the process of reviewing this UI.

[image]

All the tabs on top navigation bar can also be opened directly by clicking there links available in Dashboard view. 
In the UI, tabs that can be accessed from inside the Dashboard are placed at the same level with dashboard on top navigation bar.

I have multiple tabs in my UI.

1. Dashboard
2. Tab A
3. Tab B
4. Tab C
5. Tab D

Since the Dashboard gives an overall view of the UI, it contains link to all the tabs A, B, C, D i.e. Dashboard is the view of all the tabs in the UI. Clicking on any tab link from Dashboard view takes you to that tab an automatically select that tab from top navigation bar.

Should all the tabs on top of the UI be placed at the same level as that of Dashboard? According to my understanding, these tabs come under Dashboard as Dashboard is the parent containing all these tabs. What could be best possible way to navigation of Dashboard and other sub-tabs.

What other improvements do you think are required in this UI? Anything related to placement, positioning, UI principles anything which can make the user experience better is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: hmm, asking for ui concepts.... i dont know about that , but i think its not allowed

Comment: Yep, ageed with above post. This belongs to the UX part of the forum